# Copy the file from one folder to the other and add a time stamp as a suffix when copying batch script

Tags: batch-file, copy, move

I have a requirement to move the files once processed to a new folder and we will need to add a time stamp as suffix to the file that is moved. In a day, we might be receiving the same file(s) multiple times. I am a novice to batch scripting.

For Ex:

```
Source Folder: 

C:\SourceFiles 

a.xml, 
b.xml,
c.xml 

When I copy/move the files to the destination folder, this is how they need to look as below

Destination Folder: 

C: \DestinationFiles

a_08082013_10_16.xml, 
b_08082013_10_16.xml,
c_08082013_10_16.xml
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%n in ('date /t') do set thisdate=%%n
:: replace '/' with '-' as /'s don't work in file names.
set thisdate=%thisdate:/=-%
for /f "tokens=*" %%n in ('time /t') do set thistime=%%n
:: replace ':' with '-'
set thistime=%thistime::=-%
set firstfolder=c:\first_folder
set secondfolder=c:\second_folder

for /r "%firstfolder%" %%n in (*) do call :movefile "%%~nn" "%%~xn" "%%~dpn"
goto :EOF

:movefile
move "%~3\%~1%~2" "%secondfolder%\%~1_%thisdate%-%thistime%-%random%%~2"
```

Note: The output of the date and time commands depends on windows date / time settings. You can't control that from the prompt. If you need to control the output programmatically, it would likely be best to use another language (e.g. vbscript) or a third party utility (e.g. [windows version of GNU date command](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)).

Don't put the second folder under the first one as 'for /r' walks the entire sub-tree starting at first_folder and moves any files it finds to second folder, renaming them in the process.

We add a random value to the end, to take care of duplicates that are processed at the same time.

If there are multiple subfolders, 'move' won't make new folders. In that case, you might prefer robocopy or xcopy (type robocopy /? or xcopy /? at the prompt for help with these commands). What the above does is to move everything from all subfolders of the input folder to one output folder.